# Synchronize two Galleries

Tags: android, gallery, synchronize

I have an activity with two galleries. I want to synchronise both galleries so when I'm moving in one gallery, I should move the other gallery to match the same item.

I don't know how to accomplish this. I though it could be done by synchronising the onScroll event, I followed a good attempt on this, but it doesn't work. I assume it's because I'm not interested on the scroll event, maybe on the fling event?

Anyway, I don't know which is the proper event to observe and how to implement this. Can you help me out?

Comment: Pls share ur solution .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to just use one `Gallery` and have the `View` that it displays display both your items?

Comment: unfortunately that's not an option. However, I did find the solution; you can forward the fling event from one gallery two another playing with custom Galleries and Event Listeners and/or setSelection method. The first approach not always selects the same item on the reflected gallery. The second solution is working, however I can't tell if I'm missing some rolling effects, but is working. Thanks

Comment: Sorry my suggestion wasn't much help, but glad you answered your own question, make sure to add it as an answer and mark it as Answered

Comment: In this case I really regret @lblasa didn't post his solution here. Left us without the real solution, dude.

Comment: Hey Boris, I will post a sample code with the solution this week as soon as I find the time to strip extra stuff from there. L