# synchronize scrolling of gallery views

Tags: android, scroll, gallery

I've been stuck with this situation for few days now. My problem is I've multiple gallery views and I want to make the scrolling of all the gallery views synchronized. So if one gallery view is scrolled I need to scroll all the other gallery Views in my layout at the same time and the entire view should seem like it's one coherent view getting scrolled and not multiple views.

I've to use multiple gallery views and using a horizontalScrollView or anything else doesn't seem to be a good option in my case.

I found a similar question here:
[Synchronize two Galleries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625522/synchronize-two-galleries) but there are no solutions.

Right now I'm out of ideas and any pointers will be helpful